# Position a sheet at a row in NSTableView

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'm trying to position a sheet within an NSTableView just below a certain row.  I have the row number and have been successfully able to position the sheet at the right column but not the right row.

Apparently NSRect is drawing up from the bottom of the window containing `tableView` and I can't figure out how to have it identify the row...  I know how to position the sheet at a button or text field `NSRect cellRect = [myButton frame];` but not at a row...

Any suggestions or pointers would be very helpful, thanks!

```
- (NSRect)window:(NSWindow *)window willPositionSheet:(NSWindow *)sheet usingRect:(NSRect)rect {
    //the row number is stored as a user default - convoluted but it is what it is
    int rowNumber = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"p"] intValue];
    NSRect cellFrame = [tableView frameOfCellAtColumn:2 row:rowNumber];
    cellFrame.size.height = 0;
    return cellFrame;
}
```

Comment: You'll need to translate the frame into the windows coordinate system

Comment: Thanks, that got me on the right track.  I used the following to properly position the sheet.  Note the 140 offset that's unique to my window... `NSInteger y = rectOfCellInSuperview.origin.y;
    NSInteger screenHeight = [[[NSScreen screens] objectAtIndex:0] frame].size.height;
    NSSize myNSWindowSize = [tableView frame].size;

    NSInteger yFromBottom =  myNSWindowSize.height - y - 140;

    NSIndexSet *indexSet = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:rowNumber];
    NSRect cellFrame = NSMakeRect ( 218, yFromBottom, 100, 30 );
    cellFrame.size.height = 0;
    return cellFrame;`

Comment: Glad I was able to help. You should post this as an answer and accept it to "close" this question :)